# Action bar tabs on Samsung Galaxy note 10 running 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an application that uses Action bar with 3 tabs in portrait mode. All works except that  Tabs are not centered when running on Samsung Galaxy Note 10, instead they are left justified.

Same app code runs fine on other devices with different OS versions e.g. 4.0.2, 4.2.0 etc

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Yes. I have tried another Samsung 10 inch tablet with 4.0.2 as well as the emulator running 4.1.2 and it works fine. I will upload the picture as well.

Comment: Can you post your `AndroidManifest.xml`'s `<supports-screens .. />` tag?

Comment: What does it have to do with Support screens?

Comment: Where these other devices the same screen size and density as the Note 10?

Comment: Yes. Same size and density

Comment: Yep I run into same issue, other devices has tab centered, but one not